# How to change JButton text with a method from a seperate class?

Tags: java, swing, text, jbutton

I'm trying to change the text on a JButton when I call this method

```
public Piece select() {
        if (this.unit_here != null) {
            namedisplay.setText(this.unit_here.name);
        }
    }
```

Here's the full class the method's in

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class BoardWrapper {
    private Piece unit_here;
    private String terrain_here;
    private int terrain_duration;
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public BoardWrapper(int x2, int y2) {
        x = x2;
        y = y2;
    }
    public Piece select() {
        if (this.unit_here != null) {
            namedisplay.setText(this.unit_here.name);
        }
    }

}
```

I've declared the JButton public, yet the BoardWrapper class can't resolve it

```
public JButton namedisplay = new JButton("Unit");
```

Comment: How should the `BoardWrapper` class know that `namedisplay` is meant to be the property of a certain other class. You need to tell it that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your button public static, and call it by adding its class name before.
so if your Button is inside class A and you want access it from class B, you can do it like this:

```
A.buttonName.setText("abc");
```

Remember to declare it static.

```
public static Button buttonName = new Button ("unit");
```